# TCP connection socket overflowed vs dropped

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, netstat

I'm investigating a performance issue that server performance gets degraded with low memory, CPU, and IO usage. I found those two values by this command.

```
$ netstat -s | grep -i listen
    15848663 times the listen queue of a socket overflowed
    16003516 SYNs to LISTEN sockets dropped
```

It seems the same meaning to me. I just wonder what's the difference between them.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/646604/what-causes-syn-to-listen-sockets-dropped/646613

Answer (score 0):

An overflow of the listen queue is not the only reason a SYN to a LISTEN socket might get dropped. It also might get dropped if it's invalid. For example, a SYN sent to a broadcast or multicast address will be dropped.